# `Bad Request` error: while using passport.js + express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get, passport.js

I have the following code to redirect valid users to `/profile` url with passport.js package, but I'm receiving `Bad Request` error, the console logs: `GET /profile 400 24.100 ms - -`

I wonder what might be the cause.

```
var express = require('express')

//...

app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/profile',
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash: true
    })
);

var morgan=require('morgan')
app.use(morgan('dev')) // log every request to the console

app.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('local'),function(req,res){
    res.render('profile.ejs',{
        user: req.user
    });
})
```

Comment: did you set the Accept-Header? What does your post look like?

Comment: No I didn't set any header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was due to not including `cookie-session` in my code. I added the following lines to my code and the problem got solved.

```
var cookieSession=require('cookie-session')
app.use(cookieSession({
    keys:['secret1', 'secret2']
}))
```

Apparently `passport.js` should be used along with `cookie-session` to be able to store user session state in browser cookie.

Also, I had to change the code as follows:

```
function authenticationMiddleware(){
    return function(req,res,next){
        if(req.isAuthenticated()){
            return next()
        }
        res.redirect('/')
    }
}

app.get('/profile', authenticationMiddleware(), function(req, res) {
////the following line did NOT work, gave `Bad Request` error:
//app.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('local'),function(req,res){
    res.render('profile.ejs',{
        user: req.user
    });
})
```

[This](https://github.com/RisingStack/nodehero-authentication/blob/master/app/user/init.js) and [that](https://github.com/RisingStack/nodehero-authentication/blob/master/app/authentication/middleware.js) GitHub files helped me to write the `authenticationMiddleware()`

### UPDATE

Later I realized that I don't need to use a middle-ware. Now my code works without a middle-ware, like this:

```
app.get('/profile',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('profile.ejs',{
        user: req.user
    });
})
```